# Spring boot null pointer exception on org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am a newbie to spring boot and I have this challenge in my spring boot rest endpoints. I am getting a null exception if I try to use the `Autowired` component on a field.

Here is the exception I am getting

```
  org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'homeContoller': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'common'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'common' defined in file Common.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [Common]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405) [spring-boot-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
        at Application.main(Application.java:23) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.2.11.RELEASE.jar:2.2.11.RELEASE]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'common' defined in file Common.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [Common]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:313) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:294) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1203) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [Common]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:217) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:309) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        ... 37 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at Common.<init>(Common.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        ... 39 common frames omitted
```

and here is my java code

```
  @Component
    public class Common {
    
/* tried this and still not working(does not change locale per request it pick default language)
     @Autowired
public Common(LanguageTranslator translator)
{
   this.translator=translator;
    SUBJECT_EXISTS =translator.translate("SUBJECT_EXISTS");
}
*/
        @Autowired
        LanguageTranslator translator;
    
        public  String SUBJECT_EXISTS =translator.translate("SUBJECT_EXISTS") ;//failing error
    
    }   
    
    @Component
    public class LanguageTranslator {
    
    
        private  ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;
    
        @Autowired
        public LanguageTranslator(ResourceBundleMessageSource resourceBundleMessageSource)
        {
            this.messageSource=resourceBundleMessageSource;
        }
    
    
    
        public  String translate(String msg) {
            Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
            return messageSource.getMessage(msg, null, locale);
        }
    
    
    }
    
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public class HomeContoller {
    
    
    
        @Autowired
        Common  common;
    
    
        @GetMapping("/")
        public String home() {
    
            return "Home page";
        }
    
        @RequestMapping(value = "/demo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ResponseEntity all_menu_assignment(HttpServletRequest req)  {
    
    
            return  ResponseEntity
                    .ok().body(new ServerResponse(00,common.SUBJECT_EXISTS));
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you use constructer in Common class first init translater then try to use it

Comment: @AlperFıratKaya kindly show demo code

Comment: What is hard to understand about the suggestion? Use a constructor with constructor injection instead of field injection. You use the `translator` before it actually is injected.

Comment: @luk2302 I have tried that and still not working

Comment: Please put that attempt in the question as well, it is of course important to put the `translator.translate("SUBJECT_EXISTS")` part into the constructor as well.

Comment: @luk2302 I have over 1000 lines I need to translate Do I have to do all that in the constructor

Comment: @AlperFıratKaya  if I use your approach the locale is not getting changed dynamically per request

Comment: @luk2302 if I use your approach the locale is not getting changed dynamically per request

Comment: @NemugaDev sorry for the late response but if you need to change the locale for each request you can create a RequestContext with ThreadLocal implementation. Then create translate method in Commons then get locale from RequestContext for per request

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation of `@Autowired`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) (in general always try reading the Javadocs to understand how Spring functionality works):

> ***Autowired Fields***

> Fields are injected right after construction of a bean, before any config methods are invoked. Such a config field does not have to be public.

As you can see the field is injected after the `Common` bean is constructed, while you are trying to use it in a field initializer, *before the constructor finishes*. You can try constructor injection instead:

```
public String SUBJECT_EXISTS;

@Autowired
public Common(LanguageTranslator translator) {
    this.translator = translator;
    SUBJECT_EXISTS = translator.translate("SUBJECT_EXISTS");
}
```

**Side note:** Naming fields with uppercase is a bad practice in Java, since the field is not final. It should be more like `subjectExists`.

Comment: Well explained, you beat me by about a minute, +1

Comment: @M A I have over 1000 lines I need to translate Do I have to do all that in the constructor

Comment: @M A if I use your approach the locale is not getting changed dynamically per request

Comment: @NemugaDev if something is supposed to change dynamically a field is the wrong tool to use, you need a method instead that calls `translate` whenever asked instead of saving it into a local field. Note that this request is unrelated to the actual question because your original code would have had the same issue so far.

Comment: @NemugaDev If the translation should be done per request, then you should not do the translation in the constructor or field initializer. Instead it should be done in a method just like luk2302 suggested.